# Finding common IDs in different .txt files and appending additional corrisponding lines

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to find common IDs present in two files and print out the result into a new file appending the additional lines corresponding to those IDs.How can I do this?

Input file1.txt

```
F775_23607  EMT15298  GO:0003674    molecular_function PF08268  345
F775_00510  EMT20601  GO:0005515    protein binding    PF08268  456
F775_00510  EMT23774  GO:0003674    molecular_function PF00646  134
F775_00510  EMT23774  GO:0005515    protein binding    PF03106  888
F775_23182  EMT33502  GO:0003677    DNA binding    PF03106  789
```

Input file2.txt

```
contig15    EMT15298  95.27 148
contig18    EMT04099  97.95 293 
contig18    EMT20601  92.83 293 
contig18    EMT23062  93.17 293
```

Desired output file (I want to be able to decide which lines to print and which not)

```
EMT15298  GO:0003674 molecular_function PF08268
EMT20601  GO:0005515 protein binding    PF08268
```

My script (which, basically, prints only the column, which is in common)

```
fileA = open("file1.txt",'r')
fileB = open("file2.txt",'r')
output = open("results.txt",'w')
fileA.next()

setA = set()
for line1 in fileA:
    listA = line1.split('\t')
    setA.add(listA[1])
setB = set()
for line1 in fileB:
    listB = line1.split('\t')
    setB.add(listB[1])
for key in setA & setB:
    output.writelines(key+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict`s instead of `set`s:

```
fileA = open("file1.txt",'r')
fileB = open("file2.txt",'r')
output = open("results.txt",'w')

dictA = dict()
for line1 in fileA:
    listA = line1.split('\t')
    dictA[listA[1]] = listA

dictB = dict()
for line1 in fileB:
    listB = line1.split('\t')
    dictB[listB[1]] = listB

for key in set(dictA).intersection(dictB):
    output.write(dictA[key][1] + '\t' + dictA[key][2] + '\t' + dictA[key][3] + '\t' + dictA[key][4] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your first text file contains all of the "fields" for the output we can reduce the logic and number of steps slightly.

First we open the two input files and read them into lists:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as a, open('file2.txt','r') as b:
    fileA = [l.rstrip('\n').split('\t')[1:5] for l in a.readlines()]
    fileB = [l.rstrip('\n').split('\t')[1:] for l in b.readlines()]
```

So now we have two lists, `fileA` and `fileB`. You'll notice the slice notation on both of them. Since `fileA` has all of the values you want for the output it is now ready, it just needs filtered against the second list. I've also removed the first item from both lists so we can use the `EMT...` values for comparison.

Now we can check if `fileB` contains (not in it's entirety) `fileA` and write the matches to the results file:

```
with open('results.txt','w') as o:
    for line in fileA:
        if any(line[0] in l for l in fileB):
            o.write('%s\n' % '\t'.join(line))
```

`results.txt` is once again tab-delimited with the corresponding matches:

```
EMT15298    GO:0003674  molecular_function  PF08268
EMT20601    GO:0005515  protein binding PF08268
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do a "join" operation you can use unix join command specifying second column, for a tab delimited file it would be just like:

```
join file1.txt file2.txt -j2
```

You need to have the rows sorted, otherwise it will not work, however you can also use the sort command also available.

In addition, to select the columns you want to use you can use a pipe to the cut function:

```
join file1.txt file2.txt -j2 | cut -f2,3,4,5
```